# CLA Propagate Term: Xor vs Or Gate

Tags: carry-look-ahead

Okay say I have to use a CLA adder to implement the addition of two 2-bit numbers, X = x<sub>1</sub>x<sub>0</sub>, Y = y<sub>1</sub>y<sub>0</sub>. And say I have to write down the logical expression for the final carry-out.

So C<sub>1</sub> or the first carryout would be x<sub>0</sub>y<sub>0</sub> + C<sub>0</sub>(X<sub>0</sub>+Y<sub>0</sub>). Now if we let x<sub>0</sub>y<sub>0</sub> = g<sub>0</sub> and x<sub>0</sub> + y<sub>0</sub> = p<sub>0</sub>,

we get: C<sub>1</sub> = g<sub>0</sub> + C<sub>0</sub>(p<sub>0</sub>).

Then C<sub>2</sub> or the Final carry out = g<sub>1</sub> + C<sub>1</sub>(p<sub>1</sub>) where C<sub>1</sub> = g<sub>0</sub> + C<sub>0</sub>(p<sub>0</sub>)

so C<sub>2</sub> = g<sub>1</sub> + p<sub>1</sub>g<sub>0</sub> + p<sub>1</sub>C<sub>0</sub>p<sub>0</sub>.

Now my question is instead of letting the propagate term or p<sub>1</sub> or p<sub>0</sub> be x<sub>i</sub> + y<sub>i</sub> we let it be x<sub>i</sub> xor y<sub>i</sub> which is a valid implementation taught in many books.

My question is why? Why should one choose the Xor gate over the or gate. Are there any benefits it provides?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what your question and assumptions are. A schematic would clarify it, perfectly, I think. You might consider adding one. Is this a full-adder question with three inputs and two outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For computing the carry propagate term both the expressions

- P<sub>i</sub> = A<sub>i</sub> or B<sub>i</sub>
- P<sub>i</sub> = A<sub>i</sub> xor B<sub>i</sub>

works since the only difference in the truth tables of XOR and OR is when A=1 and B=1. However in the following expression:

C<sub>1</sub> = g<sub>0</sub> + C<sub>0</sub>(**p<sub>0</sub>**)

the P<sub>0</sub> becomes irrelevant when A<sub>i</sub>=1 and B<sub>i</sub>=1 since the Carry Generate term (A<sub>i</sub>B<sub>i</sub>=1). For this reason, in case of a CLA adder the XOR and OR gates are logically equivalent.

The OR gate is better than XOR gate for large circuits since the implementation takes lesser number of CMOS transistors. In VLSI, usually gate count is a critical factor for Area and Power considerations.

Comment: So there is no benefit in using A xor B instead of A or B?

Comment: That's correct. But however, this is a specific scenario (only in the case of CLA adder) where this interchange is possible because of the above reason. Textbooks typically show XOR because that's the logic you get when you derive it from the truth table.